# Jquery - Scroll to data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, scroll, anchor

I have a div with the data parameter 'go' containing an id of a div further down the page. Ex:

```
<div data-go="help" data-info="">text</div>
```

Currently, I can jump to the div using this code:

```
$("#icons > div").click(
    function() {
        input = $(this).data("go");
        window.location.hash = input;
    }
);
```

However,I would like a smooth transition (scrollto).
I have tried to adjust various stackoverflow solutions - but so far no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/td6qhc9q/) JSFiddle:

JavaScript

```
$("#icons > div").click(
    function() {
        var id = $(this).data("go");
        $(document.body).animate({scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top, duration: 400});
    }
);
```

HTML

```
<div id="icons">
    <div data-go="help" data-info="">text</div>
</div>

<div id="help">
    <h1>
        Help section
    </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the top [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) position value of the target element, then use jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to animate the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) property of `body`:

```
var input = $(this).data("go");
jQuery(document.body).animate({
   scrollTop:jQuery("#"+input).offset().top+"px"
});
```

Demo

```js
$("#text").click(function() {    
    var input = $(this).data("go");
    var top = jQuery("#"+input).offset().top;
    jQuery(document.body).animate({
       scrollTop:top+"px"
    },1000);
});
```

```css
#spacer {
  height:1500px;
}
#help {
  height:250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" data-go="help" data-info="">text</div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="help">Help</div>
```